# Изменяется размер изображения ImageButton после setImageResource(), что делать

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

После определенного события изменяю ресурс изображения кнопки. Картинка большая, после изменения отображается обрезанной в оригинальном размере. До вызова setImageResource() все нормально, а после нет. Вот пример:
[image: Пример отображения кнопок]

Вот код activity_main.xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_switch"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_on"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ip_address"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch_status" />
```

Вот событие изменение изображения кнопки:

```
switch (text){
            case "0":
                output_switch("ON");
                button_switch.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_on);
                break;
            case "1":
                output_switch("OFF");
                button_switch.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_off);
                break;
        }
```

Не могу найти ответ как решить этот вопрос.

Comment: у вас может быть просто изображение R.drawable.btn_off с непрозрачным фоном

Comment: Фон прозрачный, но изображение увеличивается и обрезается границами ImageButton в 250dp. То есть, размер кнопки не меняется, 250dp, а изображение в ней становится оригинального размера, огромным

Comment: @Rodney, хорошо что смогли найти решение сами, единственное что мне показалось странным что вы в xml задаете background, а в коде вместо того же background пишите setImageResource

Comment: @Tiarait, если я в коде использую setImageResource, говорит, что нужно указывать в Int. Поэтому так, наверное неправильно но работает. Появился другой вопрос, Хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку она отображалась другой картинкой, "кнопка нажата". Если делать все через xml, то хорошо. Но у меня два состояния, которые срабатывают в зависимости от того, какое сообщение пришло. И я не могу найти решение как сделать так, чтобы было три состояния: Кнопка нажата, кнопка когда пришло "0" и кнопка, когда пришёл "0".

Answer (score 0):

Помогло добавление свойства android:scaleType="fitXY":

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_switch"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_on"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ip_address"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch_status" />
```

Вот что вышло:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]